# WCF first try: How to make BasicHttpBinding work (client and server on same machine)

Tags: c#, wcf

> No socket connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I implemented boilerplate code from a textbook (published in 2008) for a WCF service and client. Both run on the same machine under Windows 10, with normal user accounts (no admin).

I studied the information in the book to find a solution for this problem, but I do not understand what they are talking about.

### Service

```
using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("http://localhost:8123/Service1")))
{
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Service1Http");
    host.Open();
}
```

This works with admin privileges (not good, but OK for the first try).

### Client

```
var ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8123/Service1/Service1Http");

var proxy = ChannelFactory<IService1>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);

string s = proxy.SayHello();
```

An exception is thrown on the last line and says that the connection is "actively refused."

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to wrong configuration for the proxies between server/client. I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) will help.

Comment: it says
>configures the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) proxy server.

but I do not have a Proxy Server. AND: both client and server run on THE SAME machine

Comment: Well, actually I did not only 'study the information in the book' but also all information in StackOverflow and other places Googel pointed me to - but I really do not understand what they are talking about.

Comment: Well, shame on me. The server is immediately closed ..... So the error message is a bit misleading. "actively refused" is not very correct.

Comment: using ( var host = new ServiceHost( typeof( Service1 ), new Uri( "http://localhost:8123/Service1")))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint( typeof( IService1 ), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Service1Http");
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate the service host");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

Comment: So, the basic communication is working between the two (heaven thanks...)

Comment: One questionstill remains: How can I make the server to run without admin privileges?

Comment: @ProgrammingRookie What level of admin privilages is the lowest that can run the server fully?

Comment: Cents02: How can I give the server privileges? I have a normal user account, which cannot run it, and the admin account, that can. I would like to have the server run with a standard user privileges because the functionality itself does not need any special privileges. I cannot understan why only for the communication part I need admin privileges.

Comment: @ProgrammingRookie A workaround can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5774656/10354154)

Comment: Yes, the 'temporary URI' .... does work, but canI use it over the internet and through firewall later? For testing purposes on a local machine, I can use a pipe or TCP binding anyway. The goal is to make it reachable from the outside. Maybe this should not work on purpose, for security reasons I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you said, the client needs to invoke the service before the server shuts down automatically. You can use the following statement to prevent the server from shutting down automatically.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:13020");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            using (ServiceHost sh=new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb==null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("service is ready...");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is closed now...");
                };
                sh.Open();

                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
            }
        }  
}
```

> One questionstill remains: How can I make the server to run without admin privileges?

You can give your application account the permissions it needs. To do this, we reserve the URL namespace for the account, allowing the relevant application to register that URL. We can use the **Netsh** command (this tool requires administrator privileges).

```
Netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=domain\user
```

You should take the place of **domain\user** with your actual account, and use the actual port instead of **8080**, For example administrator.

```
Netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8123/ user=administrator
```

“**+**” is a wildcard character that indicates that all network adapter requests can access this url.
Here is official document about this tool.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Http/netsh-commands-for-http
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Interesting. Did not know that and will look into. Thank you!